# Prevent username enumeration while registering a user in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-spi

I'm currently working with *Keycloak* version 16.1.1. During user registration, if an email that is already present in the database is entered, *keyclaok* generates an "email_in_use" error. I aim to modify this behavior. Specifically, when a user attempts to register with an email that already exists, I want to redirect him to the successful registration page. On this page, the user will be prompted to click a link sent to his email inbox for verification.

in the registration flow, I created a copy of the registration flow where I replaced the "Profile Validation" execution with a new `ProfileValidationIgnoreEmailInUse` execution.

```
public class ProfileValidationIgnoreEmailInUse implements FormAction, FormActionFactory {
@Override
    public void validate(ValidationContext context) {
    // copied the same code as org.keycloak.authentication.forms.RegistrationProfile, but I modified the email check part
    ...
    if (emailValid && !context.getRealm().isDuplicateEmailsAllowed() && context.getSession().users().getUserByEmail(email, context.getRealm()) != null) {
            logger.infof("TTEST skipped error email in use");
        }
    ... 
    }
}
```

Now when the user enters an existing email in the register form, I get a new error: `ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement` at `org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.addUser(UserStorageManager.java:247)` which is normal because the username already exists in the database. What would be the next change I have to make in order to ignore this ConstraintViolationException exception?

Comment: You can't ignore the exception per-se, as the user already exists. What's your initial idea? If another "john.doe@example.com" registers, the registration "succeeds" and the user clicks a link for the email to be sent? And then, the original John Doe gets the email? The solution seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: Also, take a look at this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/69370/preventing-user-enumeration-on-registration-page

Comment: thank you Manuel for your feedback. The idea is to avoid username enumeration on the register page. In the sent email to "john.doe@example.com" we can for example ignore sending the email if it already exists, but at the same time we continue to show the success page after registering form submit

Comment: I think you are just masking the problem. Instead of registering, you could just try to login with the email address. If you try to login with an existing username (but wrong password) you will see a "invalidPasswordMessage". If the username is unknown you will see "invalidUsernameMessage". That would be another think you need to change. That's a never ending process. Why do you have the requirement to do your task?

Comment: My task is for a security enhancement.